# SELECT MAX Com mais de três colunas

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tenho a seguinte tabela:

```
jobname     aplicacao   start           end             tempo_de_execucao
PROCESSO_C  APLICACAO_C 3/4/2020 3:01   3/4/2020 5:39   2:37:26             
PROCESSO_E  APLICACAO_D 3/4/2020 6:00   3/4/2020 6:41   0:40:51             
PROCESSO_D  APLICACAO_B 3/4/2020 15:29  3/4/2020 17:25  1:56:18             
PROCESSO_C  APLICACAO_C 3/5/2020 3:01   3/5/2020 5:40   2:38:51             
PROCESSO_E  APLICACAO_D 3/5/2020 6:00   3/5/2020 6:42   0:42:15             
PROCESSO_D  APLICACAO_B 3/5/2020 12:27  3/5/2020 12:28  0:01:37             
PROCESSO_B  APLICACAO_B 3/5/2020 22:59  3/6/2020 18:56  19:57:05            
PROCESSO_C  APLICACAO_C 3/6/2020 3:01   3/6/2020 5:52   2:50:54             
PROCESSO_E  APLICACAO_D 3/6/2020 6:00   3/6/2020 6:40   0:39:51             
PROCESSO_D  APLICACAO_B 3/6/2020 16:24  3/6/2020 16:26  0:01:36             
PROCESSO_B  APLICACAO_B 3/6/2020 23:01  3/7/2020 13:27  14:25:07            
PROCESSO_C  APLICACAO_C 3/7/2020 3:01   3/7/2020 6:45   3:43:53             
PROCESSO_A  APLICACAO_A 3/7/2020 5:00   3/8/2020 5:04   24:04:14
```

Estou tentando executar uma query para me trazer os 05 processos mais demorados, sem repetir o nome, ou seja precisaria desse resultado:

```
jobname     aplicacao   start           end             tempo_de_execucao
PROCESSO_A  APLICACAO_A 3/7/2020 5:00   3/8/2020 5:04   24:04:14            
PROCESSO_B  APLICACAO_B 3/5/2020 22:59  3/6/2020 18:56  19:57:05            
PROCESSO_C  APLICACAO_C 3/7/2020 3:01   3/7/2020 6:45   3:43:53             
PROCESSO_D  APLICACAO_B 3/4/2020 15:29  3/4/2020 17:25  1:56:18             
PROCESSO_E  APLICACAO_D 3/5/2020 6:00   3/5/2020 6:42   0:42:15
```

Só que quando executo a query:

```
select A.job_mem_name AS JOBNAME,
A.application AS APLICACAO,
max (A.start_time) AS START,
max (A.end_time) AS END,
max (A.run_time_sec::real /60 /60 / 24) AS TEMPO_DE_EXECUCAO
from runinfo_history A
where A.ended_status = '16' and A.job_id IS NOT NULL and A.job_mem_name in 
(SELECT B.job_name
from def_ver_job B
where B.memname <> 'AFT')
group by A.job_mem_name, A.application
order by max (A.run_time_sec) desc limit 05;
```

me traz o seguinte valor, start time é exibido a data da ultima execução e não a data real.

```
jobname     aplicacao   start           end             tempo_de_execucao
PROCESSO_A  APLICACAO_A 3/7/2020 5:00   3/8/2020 5:04   24:04:14
PROCESSO_B  APLICACAO_B 3/6/2020 23:01  3/7/2020 13:27  19:57:05
PROCESSO_C  APLICACAO_C 3/7/2020 3:01   3/7/2020 6:45   3:43:53
PROCESSO_D  APLICACAO_B 3/6/2020 16:24  3/6/2020 16:26  1:56:18
PROCESSO_E  APLICACAO_D 3/6/2020 6:00   3/6/2020 6:40   0:42:15
```

Se eu não coloco a expressão max em (`A.start_time` e `A.end_time`), vem a mensagem:

```
ERROR:  column "a.start_time" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 3: A.start_time AS START,
```

Se coloco na query em group by os campos A.start_time e A.end_time o resultado é esse, ou seja repete o nome da aplicação.

```
jobname     aplicacao   start           end             tempo_de_execucao   
PROCESSO_A  APLICACAO_A 3/7/2020 5:00   3/8/2020 5:04   24:04:14            
PROCESSO_B  APLICACAO_B 3/5/2020 22:59  3/6/2020 18:56  19:57:05            
PROCESSO_B  APLICACAO_B 3/6/2020 23:01  3/7/2020 13:27  14:25:07            
PROCESSO_C  APLICACAO_C 3/7/2020 3:01   3/7/2020 6:45   3:43:53             
PROCESSO_C  APLICACAO_C 3/6/2020 3:01   3/6/2020 5:52   2:50:54
```

Lembrando que o resultado que eu preciso seria:

Comment: Avalie a utilização da cláusula `DISTINCT ON (expr, ...)` precedendo a lista de seleção (não é a DISTINCT simples). https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-select-lists.html#QUERIES-DISTINCT

Comment: 1 obtenha o maior tempo de execução por jobname com um subselect com max , 2 com esta sql obtenha os X maiores

Comment: O problema é que a minha tabela contém mais de 19.000 registros, e se coloco o DISTINCT ON, não consigo colocar a expressão: order by max (A.run_time_sec) desc limit 10; pois vem a mensagem: ERROR:  SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions
LINE 1: SELECT DISTINCT ON (A.job_mem_name)

Comment: Tente classificar apenas por `A.jobname, A.run_time_sec`, não utilize a função max.

Answer (score 3):

**Utilize uma [Window Function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/tutorial-window.html)**

Utilize o particionamento pelo `jobname`, e a ordenação decrescente da duração:

```
select
    t.*,
    rank() over w as i
from t
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY jobname ORDER BY duracao DESC)
```

Resultado:

> Observe a última coluna, `i` que é o rank de cada registro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois você seleciona filtrando apenas os registros de rank = 1:

```
SELECT x.jobname,
       x.aplicacao,
       x.start,
       x."end",
       x.duracao
FROM
  (SELECT t.*,
          rank() OVER w AS i
   FROM t WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY jobname
                       ORDER BY duracao DESC)) x
WHERE x.i = 1
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1bf94/3

Comment: Rovann, muito obrigado deu certo utilizando o particionamento. Minha query ficou assim:

select
job_mem_name AS JOBNAME,
application AS APLICACAO,
start_time AS STAR,
end_time AS END,
run_time_sec::real /60 /60 / 24 AS TEMPO_DE_EXECUCAO
from
(select job_mem_name,
application, start_time, end_time,run_time_sec,
rank() over w as i
from runinfo_history
where runinfo_history.start_time between '2020-04-03 00:00:01' and '2020-04-10 23:00:01'
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY job_mem_name ORDER BY run_time_sec DESC)) A
where A.i = 1

Comment: Unica coisa que não consegui fazer foi utilizar uma segunda tabela no primeiro Select, ou seja seria o tempo médio de execução que fica na tabela avg_run_info, que algo tipo assim:

Comment: select
job_mem_name AS JOBNAME,
application AS APLICACAO,
start_time AS STAR,
end_time AS END,
avg_run_info.avg_run_time::real /60 /60 / 24,
run_time_sec::real /60 /60 / 24 AS TEMPO_DE_EXECUCAO
from
(select job_mem_name,
application, start_time, end_time,avg_run_info.avg_run_time,run_time_sec,
rank() over w as i
from runinfo_history
inner join avg_run_info on A.job_mem_name = avg_run_info.job_mem_name
where runinfo_history.start_time between '2020-04-03 00:00:01' and '2020-04-10 23:00:01'
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY job_mem_name ORDER BY run_time_sec DESC)) A
where A.i = 1

Comment: Olá @TulioNorbertoPadilhaRomanin, complicado ver pelos comentários, mas faça o join fora do sub-select. Se a resposta resolve sua pergunta, marque-a como resposta por favor. Se necessário, altere o SQL Fiddle e mande o link que tentamos continuar a te ajudar.

Comment: @Rovannn Linhalis, eu consegui, fazendo como vc falou, muito obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: @TulioNorbertoPadilhaRomanin não se esqueça de marcar a resposta. Vi que é novo na comunidade, dê uma olhada nos conteúdos de como a comunidade funciona... tem o [tour] e o https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8045/guia-de-sobreviv%c3%aancia-do-stack-overflow-em-portugu%c3%aas?cb=1